# Color bands for cubism.js

Tags: d3.js, cubism.js

Can someone point me in the direction of what I should be tweaking to get deterministic color band? For example, if they array of colors contains 6 colors, I would like the values 10-30 to always go to the 5th color band, 50-80 to the 6th, etc.

(in case someone is wondering why I need such an odd thing, right now the value 30 shows up in several different colors, depending on what other values are in the set -- can be pretty confusing for a user over time). I thought of restricting the min and max values in the set to achieve stable colors but that would distort the lables. Also, ideally, I would like to specify the mapping of input data value to color myself

Answer (score 3):

This won't let you do arbitrary assignments of values to colors, but you can set the min and max  values cubism uses to assign colors with the `extent` option:

```
var context = cubism.context();
var horizon = context.horizon();
horizon.extent([-80,80]);
```

The extent will then be divided up evenly among the color bands you have set.